# How to prevent browser getting stuck on Angular route when navigating back through browser history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, browser-history

I'm using ui-router and Angular 1.4.7. For context, everything I've tried works when navigating forwards (including away from the route) or backwards within the route, but never works when navigating back to a *different* route.

Within the controller for the route I get stuck on I am using $location.search() to update my route parameters and $locationChangeSuccess to fire a function after that change. Currently, I end up stuck on the route if I try to go back to a different route. I've tried using $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess to detect the route (via slicing the newUrl and oldUrl params) I'm attempting to navigate back to, but it always shows up as the current route (though this does work if I'm navigating forwards).

**Update: Some of the code**

```
// routeIGetStuckOn.js excerpt
$stateProvider
  .state('routeIGetStuckOn', {
    url: '/routeIGetStuckOn?optionalParams',
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    templateUrl: 'app/routes/routeIGetStuckOn/routeIGetStuckOn.html',
    controller: 'routeIGetStuckOnCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// routeIGetStuckOn.controller.js excerpt

// When params in URL is updated, fire a function
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
 loadNewData();
});

//Use $location.search in various different functions with different types of new data
$location.search('optionalParams', newData);
```

**Update: Show URL issue**

I've found a solution which I will submit as an answer in case anyone else ends up in this situation. This is what I am preventing:

1. Start at `website.com/randomRoute`
2. Go to `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn`
3. Update param on click to `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn?optionalParams=data`
4. Attempt to go back using browser back button to `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn` of step 2 but end up at `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn?optionalParams=`. At this point, unable to press back button to get to `website.com/randomRoute` of step 1.

Comment: Can you give examples of your routes and urls you're going between?  Code you're using?  Any reason you're not using `stateChangeSuccess`?

Comment: `$stateChangeSuccess` will only fire when going forwards through history to another route (or just clicking onto route). I'll see if I can pull out some relevant code to clarify what I'm doing. There's a lot of code though :/

Comment: If you're using it properly, `$stateChangeSuccess` will fire with a back button just fine.  I use it all the time...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to preserve the browser history and prevent navigation to `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn?optionalParams=`, instead going to `website.com/routeIGetStuckOn` as intended, by adding this code:

```
// Strip unused optional parameter on routeIGetStuckOn home page
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next){
  if (next.slice(-1) === '=') {
    $location.url($location.path());
  }
});
```

It still feels a little janky, but I haven't been able to find a better solution.